# Failed to open the file

Tags: sed, quotes

I am trying to figure out the picture date of files in a folder structure. Some of the folder names contain with whitespaces. Now I try to set the quotes, but it doesn't work.

Can anyone give me a hint?

```
  find . -name "*.jpg" -or -name "*.JPG" >> files.txt
    sed -e "s/\(.*\)/'\1'/" files.txt >> files2.txt
    for fn in `cat files2.txt`; do
    DATEI=$( echo "$fn" | cut -c 3-)
    EXIF=$(/usr/bin/exiv2 -pa --grep DateTimeOriginal "'"$PWD$DATEI | awk -F" " '{print $4","$5}')
    if [ -z "$EXIF" ]
    then
    :
    else
    echo "$PWD$DATEI,$EXIF" >> ausgabe.csv
    fi
done
echo "DONE!"
```

EDIT: This is the output that I get:

```
'/volume1/Intern/path/to/images/IMG_4206.jpg': Failed to open the file
```

Comment: So add debugging code and/or strip it down to identify which line is producing that error message and then fix it. There's only about 4 or 5 lines of code that could be producing the error message, it'll take you about as much time as posting this question did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it your result is supposed to look like

```
"/path/to/photo1.jpg","2017:01:15","22:19:15"
"/path/to/another/photo.JPG","2017:01:15","22:10:01"
```

The absolute path to the photo, then the `DateTimeOriginal` date/time, all in quotes.

`exiv2` can actually take multiple photos in the file argument, so the whole process can be simplified to a pipeline of two commands:

```sh
# Need this for the fileglob
shopt -s globstar extglob

exiv2 -pa -g DateTimeOriginal **/*.@(jpg|JPG) |
awk -v pwd="$PWD/" -v dq='"' -v OFS=',' '{
    fn = substr($0, 1, match($0, / *Exif\.Photo/)-1)
    print dq pwd fn dq,  dq $(NF-1) dq, dq $NF dq
}'
```

The shell options, `globstar` and `extglob`, enable the `**/*.*@(jpg|JPG)` expression, which returns all files ending in `jpg` or `JPG` for the whole directory tree.

`exiv2` returns only something for the files that contain `DateTimeOriginal` data. The intermediate output looks something like this (some whitespace removed):

```
dir1/photo1.jpg       Exif.Photo.DateTimeOriginal   Ascii 20  2017:01:22  10:20:36
dir1/photo3.jpg       Exif.Photo.DateTimeOriginal   Ascii 20  2017:01:22  10:20:36
dir with space/photo2.JPG  Exif.Photo.DateTimeOriginal  Ascii 20  2017:01:22 10:20:38
dir with space/photo4.JPG  Exif.Photo.DateTimeOriginal  Ascii 20  2017:01:22 10:40:09
photo5.jpg            Exif.Photo.DateTimeOriginal   Ascii 20  2017:01:24 20:06:38
photo6.JPG            Exif.Photo.DateTimeOriginal   Ascii 20  2017:01:22 10:00:55
```

This would be straightforward with awk, were it not for the paths with spaces as mentioned in the question. The `exiv2` output is space separated, and there doesn't seem to be an option to get tabs, so some awk trickery is required:

- The path of the current directory, followed by a slash, is passed into the command using `-v pwd="$PWD/"`.
- To avoid messy escaping, we define the double quote with `-v dq='"'`.
- The output field separator is set to a comma with `-v OFS=','`.
- To get the filename, we search for the index of a series of spaces followed by `Exif.Photo`, then we assign a substring that ends just before that index to `fn`.
- To print quoted and comma separated, we use our `dq` variable, prepend the filename with the path from `pwd`, and use `$(NF-1)` and `$NF` to get the second to last and last field, respectively.

The result is something like

```
"/home/benjamin/tinker/space dir/dir1/photo1.jpg","2017:01:22","10:20:36"
"/home/benjamin/tinker/space dir/dir1/photo3.jpg","2017:01:22","10:20:36"
"/home/benjamin/tinker/space dir/dir with space/photo2.JPG","2017:01:22","10:20:38"
"/home/benjamin/tinker/space dir/dir with space/photo4.JPG","2017:01:22","10:40:09"
"/home/benjamin/tinker/space dir/photo5.jpg","2017:01:24","20:06:38"
"/home/benjamin/tinker/space dir/photo6.JPG","2017:01:22","10:00:55"
```

To get this into a file, a redirection `> ausgabe.csv` has to be appended to the command.

---

As for why your command didn't work: let's look at a single file as an example. After the sed step, you have something like `'./photo5.jpg'`. Now, you use `cut -c 3-`, which gives you `/photo5.jpg'`.

In your `EXIF` line, you add another single quote, so now `exiv2` is looking for a file literally called `'/photo5.jpg'`, including the single quotes – which doesn't exist.